# how to sum a value from dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, sum

I want to sum the total price from dynamic table. The table look like this.
The data table are from split function.
[image]
How to sum the total price value when i click the total price button ?

This is the html code.

```
<script> 
function addRow(tags) <!--input funtion-->
{
var theTable = document.getElementById('table_trans').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var newRow = theTable.insertRow(-1);
for(var i=0;i<tags.length;i++)
newRow.insertCell(i).appendChild(document.createTextNode(tags[i]));
}

function addTransaction()
{
addRow(document.getElementById('transaction').value.split(','));
}
</script>

<div class="container">

        <div class="form" style="margin-top: 50px;">

            <div class="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3">Input</label>
                    <div class="">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="transaction" placeholder="Input Transaction">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="addTransaction()">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <table id="table_trans" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Total Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <input type="button" value="Total Price" onclick="sumPrice()" class="btn btn-success" />
                        </td>
                        <td id="area_total"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
 <!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Do you hold the data in a javascript model at all, or is it purely contained within the table in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of doing it:

1. At the moment of generating your table sum up the values and then output it in total row.

Ex:

```
var totalPrice = 0;

// ...
// Somewhere in the code handle totalPrice value
// ...

function sumPrice() {
    $("#totalPrice").html(totalPrice)
}
```

2. In case you can not affect the process of table generation add some specific class to each `td`, then at `sumPrice()` query for that `td.class` and show totals.

Ex:

```
function sumPrice() {
    var totalPrice = 0;
    $("td.totalPriceRow").each(
        function(element) {
            totalPrice += parseInt(element.html(), 10);
        }
    );
    $("#totalPrice").html(totalPrice)
}
```